# Enabling go mode for emacs

Tags: emacs

I don't seem to be able to enable a go mode for emacs. C mode doesn't work without semicolons. The best I have found is the [JavaScript mode by Karl Landstrom](http://www.brgeight.se/downloads/emacs/javascript.el), since JavaScript also doesn't require semicolons.

Comment: http://golang.org/misc/emacs/ Directions included in go-mode-load.el

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try `misc/emacs/go-mode.el` ([web link](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins)) in the Go distribution.

If you are using [Emacs 24 and marmalade repo](http://sachachua.com/blog/2011/01/emacs-24-package-manager/), use `M-x package-install <RET> go-mode` to install it directly.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's in the Go distribution, not the Emacs distribution. For me it was in ~/go/misc/emacs.

Comment: You really should *not* use marmalade to install go-mode right now. The version on there is terribly outdated.

Comment: What can we do to make sure that it's _not_ terribly outdated? Using package mode is tremendously convenient...

Comment: 1) Could've used a different repository, such as MELPA 2) It's been taken care of. the marmalade version isn't terribly outdated anymore

Comment: As of now I think the right place to find that link is here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins (yours is now a 404).

Comment: Note https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el is now the canonical location of the Emacs mode for Go as it has been removed from the Go distribution. The most up-to-date version is now in the MELPA repository and can indeed be installed with `M-x package-install <RET> go-mode`.

Answer (score 24):

If your Go installs to `/usr/local/go` then add the following to your `.emacs` file.

```
;; go mode                                                                                           
(setq load-path (cons "/usr/local/go/misc/emacs" load-path))                                         
(require 'go-mode-load)
```

Answer (score 7):

### Update from 2014 for Linux users

You can now download the golang-mode for Emacs from your package manager:

- [Fedora](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/emacs-golang): `yum install emacs-golang`
- [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/stable/golang-mode): `apt-get install golang-mode`
- [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/golang-mode): `apt-get install golang-mode`

I only checked on Fedora, but the package is automatically installed and you have nothing to do except enjoying your new golang mode! And it is also updated as any other package of your system.

There are probably packages on other Linux distributions too.

Answer (score 6):

Read [Writing Go in Emacs](http://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2013/03/writing_go_in_emacs/) and [its follow-up](http://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2013/08/writing_go_in_emacs__cont__/), written by Dominik Honnef, the author of the official `go-mode`.

There he explains the story of `go-mode` and ways to install it, how to read Go documentation from inside Emacs, how to manage import statements of Go files in Emacs, how to setup autocomplete, on-the-fly syntax checking, snippets, and a lot of other super useful features for developing Go in Emacs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. It is in the source code, inside the `misc/emacs` dir.