# What do you use to write Go

Tags: ide, text-editor, go

I know its a bit too early, but I've been trying out [Go](http://golang.org) (Google's Programming Language) and its kindof annoying to write code in gedit.

So, my question: What do you use to experiment with Go?

Comment: Do we really want more than one tag for Go?

Comment: @Pynt — Since "go" seems to be the general consensus, I've retagged this and the other two questions using multiple tags for Go.

Comment: Anyone got a good "why Go?" article link somewhere?

Comment: @quillbreaker: You don't want to go, do you?

Comment: I find that the Zeus editor has good support for the Go language.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

under $GOROOT/misc there are syntax highlighting files for emacs, vim, xcode and kate. Using any of these editors should do.

Answer (score 12):

Somebody in the #go-nuts irc channel has a Go syntax file for gedit, so I would ask there if you want that.

I personally use what Rob Pike and Russ Cox use: [acme](http://acme.cat-v.org). And I know Ken Thompson still uses [sam](http://sam.cat-v.org).

Edit: For those interested, [I have created a page to collect Go syntax highlighting files for various text editors](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/). If you have any that is not included there let me know and I'll be happy to add it.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping in to post the obligatory [vim](http://www.vim.org/) answer.

Comment: Why does you link point to perl.org ?

Comment: Haha oops .. I was browsing perl earlier and pasted someone the link in a chat. Guess when I went to vim, I didn't copy and pasted the wrong one :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll see your vim and raise you one emacs.

Comment: Are you implying that emacs is superior to vim as a text editor?(Notice I said text editor and not OS, no comparison there)

Comment: So that's like a vim and a half?

Comment: Oh no! he just went all-in.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has released a bundle for TextMate if you're on a Mac. (just search the Go Google Group discussions).

Answer (score 2):

After searching for alternatives, I found [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/8b3142bc053eba63/090d2d539fdb0538?lnk=gst&q=gedit#090d2d539fdb0538). Mr Perez created a syntax file for gtk sourceview, so that editors such as gedit, scribes etc. can have syntax highlighting for Go~

just copy [this](http://91.121.30.198/static/go/go.lang) to /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/

Answer (score 2):

Some info no-one has mentioned yet: The Go distribution comes with a program called **gofmt** which provides a standardized format for the language. You can run golfed Go through it and get clean output. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726698/code-golf-sierpinskis-triangle/1727227#1727227).

I am always using **Emacs** so I initially started thinking there would be no Go mode for Emacs and asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715464/emacs-lisp-mode-for-go/1715502#1715502). Then a minute after I'd asked I had the notion to do `find . -name "*.el"` at the top of the Go source tree and was able to answer my own question. Some other people seem to have found the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) could probably work with some tweaking of the syntax file for C++.

To see the differences read [Go For C++ Programmers](http://golang.org/doc/go_for_cpp_programmers.html)

Answer (score 0):

vim or emacs?  I haven't played around with Go yet, but those are the only editors I use when programming for myself.

Comment: You're just ASKING for a flame war. (go vim btw)

Comment: 2+ years later... I mostly use vi.  I want to try using emacs for some prolonged period to get a better feel for the difference, though.  I included emacs to avoid a flame war, not start it.  :P  I guess it could be taken either way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find the split-window capability of kate to be quite useful in go programming.  (Ubuntu 10.4 LTS with the kate syntax highlight file added)

Hotei