# Where can I find a Vim syntax file for the go language?

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor, syntax-highlighting, go

Has anyone created a vim syntax file for the go language?

Comment: It comes with one.  Please look first.

Comment: I wholeheartedly apologize for asking a stupid question.

Comment: Dustin - muich as I'm grated by newbie questions, it was 100% decidively decided by StackOverflow's founders that the obvious/RTFMable/easy-googlable questions are 100% valid and acceptable on SO. And this one was not even that obvious/easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[go.vim](//github.com/golang/go/blob/1ec56062/misc/vim/compiler/go.vim)

There is also a syntax file on [vim.org](//vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2853).

Answer (score 10):

A vim syntax file is included in the Go distribution under misc/vim/ For syntax files for other editors see also: http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays there is a `vim-syntax-go` package in Ubuntu, which would probably be the easiest for most such users.

Answer (score 2):

This topic has been covered in detail already:

[What do you use to write Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731217/what-do-you-use-to-write-go)

Comment: Sorry, missed that one.  Thanks though.